# MySQL Workbench: On a select with joins, how to show the table each column came from?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have some large queries in our MySQL DB with multiple tables being joined. To debug them I'd like to have each column name show the table it came from.

How to do this?

Not for nothing, to the people who edit questions here. I don't appreciate having some parts of my question that aren't even close to technical edited. You just decided that "How to do this? Is better than "Does anyone know how to do this?". That's 100% style/preference and you decided I'd sound better with How to do this? When I think that sounds dumber. Just my $0.02.

Comment: Great and intriguing question! I myself would find that really useful, but unfortunately I think MySQL Workbench does not provide this feature as of yet. =/

Answer (score 2):

It's verbose, but I just use aliases in the select statement.  Here's an example distinguishing two fields from different tables using the same field name:

```
SELECT c.label as c_label, i.label as i_label FROM items i INNER JOIN categories c ON i.cat_id = c.id
```

Comment: I had thought of that, but it becomes troublesome when you have, say, 5~8 tables with _N_ columns each. But yes, indeed this is a workaround.